# Where can I ask about Electrical components or circuits?

Tags: discussion, support

Given that EE SE is about circuit/component *design* (rather than general electricity/electronics), where is the best place to ask non-design questions about electronics? Physics SE seems like the most appropriate place, but the "on topic" section for that site doesn't make that apparent, as far as I can tell.

For example: I have a question about calculating the current through a node in a circuit, but I'm not sure what influence/effect a transistor has on the resistors attached to its base and emitter. This has nothing to do with design considerations.

Comment: Any part of physics theory that is applicable to electronics is generally on-topic.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, that IS design considerations. Go ahead and ask your question.